# To list disk number using Get-Disk and check if they are online

Tags: powershell

I need to list disk number using Get-Disk within 10 disk numbers and check that they are online or not. How to achieve this?

Comment: What you actually want to do, please elaborate in the question properly. Use Get-Disk or Get-Volume?

Comment: `Get-Disk` (no parameters) should give you all you want doesn't it? Check the `Number` and `OperationalStatus` properties

Comment: @Theo How to check if there are more than 10 disk numbers or not, shouldnt it be in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you intend to do, but maybe you want something like this?

```
$disks = @(Get-Disk)
"Found $($disks.Count) disks:"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt [math]::Min($disks.Count, 10); $i++) {
    if ($disks[$i].OperationalStatus -eq 'Online') { 
        Write-Host "Disk $($disks[$i].Number) ('$($disks[$i].FriendlyName)') is online"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found 4 disks:
Disk 0 ('ST3500418AS') is online
Disk 1 ('Samsung SSD 750 EVO 250GB') is online
Disk 2 ('WDC WD7501AALS-00J7B0') is online
```

Comment: the scenario is like if there are disk numbers more than 10 , loop should exit else if the disk numbers are within 10  then list those which are online only

Comment: @Hidei Do you mean something like the edited answer?

Comment: If there is a single disk with number 0 , output doesnt reflect

Comment: @Hidei Simply force `Get-Disk` to become an array by enclosing it with `@()`. Updated the answer for you.